# How to convert a MongoDb's capped collection to non-capped collection?

Tags: mongodb, capped-collections

Due to some specific business requirement we were storing data into the MongoDB's capped collection but now complete requirement changed and we want ot preserve all records in that collection.

I am able to find "convertToCapped" command but didn't find any command to perform vise versa operation.

How can I convert it back to non-capped collection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [copy](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/) it:

```
use admin
db.runCommand( { renameCollection: "yourdb.yourcollection", to: "yourdb.oldcapped" } )
use yourdb
db.oldcapped.copyTo("yourcollection")
```

Then [ensure](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/) required indexes and [create](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/) users in uncapped `yourcollection`. Run your tests, and if you are happy with results, [drop](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.drop/) `oldcapped`.

Needless to say it should be done within maintenance window.